# How to get a point to the left/right of a vector

Tags: mathematics, unity, rotation, vector, quaternion

I have a position vector of a point in space and a quaternion for it's rotation. What i'm trying to calculate is a point too the left and a point to the right.

[image: Image showing what I want to achieve]

I have the position and rotation(quaternion) of the red dot. What I want is to get the position of the green dots. I have a float value for the distance I want these points to be.

With only the position and rotation is it possible to get a unit direction vector pointing left/right which I can multiply by my float value?

Edit: I also know the original direction vector.

Comment: Do you have the Direction vector and any fixed Vector (like UP)?

Comment: I have the original direction vector. (edited question)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given only a point and a direction there is no defined 'right' or 'left'.

Imagine being a falling raindrop, which direction is right or left for you in that case?

In order to calculate (or even define) a right or left you need two directions, typically forward and up.

You seem to already have a forward direction, so you need to define a up direction.

```
right_dir=forward X up  (cross product)
left_dir=-right
```

As you want unit vectors in these direction, you should of course normalize right & left.

Comment: I know the up direction. I also realized I know the first direction it's facing. Can I use my rotation and the vector to calculate the new forward vector and then do as you have suggested? If I can get the angle I can use the dot product with the original direction to get the new direction I think.

Comment: I assume all this is in 3D. If you have a quaternion, you can apply that to both the original forward direction and original up direction, to give you a new forward and new up. Get the cross product of the two new vectors.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I'll give it a go and mark it as the answer if it works.

Comment: +1 for "Imagine being a falling raindrop" for both illustrating the point and being sort of poetic.